# Missing Bootstrap 4 styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project, which seem to missing a lot core styles in reboot CSS and `bootstrap.css` as I compared to downloaded from bootstrap. 
My question is, is it possible that I download selective things with bootstrap 4 as it had in bootstrap 3 and if so how can i rebuild the `reboot.css` or bootstrap.css so i can have those styles again and not loosing my old ones (if the other developer override on them)

This is excerot CSS from `bootstrap.css`

```
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

and default bootstrap.css

```
article,
aside,
footer,
header,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
```